# Ensure react is imported in each create-react-app component for bundling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, babeljs, create-react-app

I am using a `create-react-app` TypeScript project as a base for a React component I will release as an independent package. To use the package externally, I must `import React from 'react'` in each component file. However, `create-react-app` uses a babel-transform that marks the React import as unnecessary. I want my environment to expect a React import where the modular code will demand it. How can I modify my `create-react-app` project to throw an error if React is not imported in every component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using `tsconfig` in a relevant issue in the `typescript` repository: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41882#issuecomment-940734525

The `jsx` compiler option needs to be set to `"react"`, not `"react-jsx"`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **eslint** to check it

Examples: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/react-in-jsx-scope.md

And use it by default in VScode with extension
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint